# NSString stringWithFormat objectForKey custom Json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This code shows my user's `username` in a UILabel named `caption`

```
caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
```

I want `caption` to instead show that user's `device token` instead of their `username`. This is how the `device token` has been used successfully in the app so far.

```
//A different Method that successfully handles the device token
 NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command",                         [_dataModel deviceToken], @"token", nil ];
```

&

```
//Another different method that successfully handles the device token with a slightly different syntax
NSDictionary *params = @{@"cmd":@"join",
                         //the red text passes user_id to _datamodels userId method and thusly to api.php's handleJoin function 
                         @"token":[_dataModel deviceToken],
                       };
```

Question: how can one write the correct syntax to show the token, as is, for the `objectforkey` value? This is what I've tried but I get a compiler warning: `no visible interface declaration for selector objectForKey`. I know this can be done, how?

```
caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"token":[_dataModel deviceToken]]];
```

**Original j son : data**

```
//Method body
-(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data
{
self = [super init];
if (self !=nil)
{
```

Comment: `[data objectForKey:@"token"]` instead?

Comment: Hey @Larme , thanks for your answer. I tried this but instead of showing the device token at runtime, `caption` simply read `@null` because it wasn't reading the true device token value. To show it, i think it has to have a similar syntax as above i.e. `@"token": [_datamodel deviceToken]` because thats where the token is actually stored in the app. I've tried all the configurations I can think of but will keep at it. I have a hunch its an easy fix.

Comment: what is your original json?

Comment: Hey @Susim , what do you mean by original j son? Thanks.

Comment: @user3233623 you have dictionary right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data[@"username"][@"token"]];
```

Comment: Hey @Oleshoko , thank you for your reply. I tried both lines of code and the `caption` label still reads `(null)` with the first line, and `token: (null)` with the second. It seems it will come down to trying as many possible configurations as possible.

Comment: ok, then, as @Susim wrote, what is your original json and how you read it in iOS app?

Comment: Hey again @Oleshko What do you guys mean exactly by original j son? I almost replied to @Susims post with this line of code `caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];` stating that the username field is a field in my database. The app uses `AFNetworking` to connect to my server url. The app uses AFNetworking `commands` like the `params` dictionary above to call a corresponding commands in a php file located in my htdocs folder.

Comment: And what is it - data? Is it NSDictionary?

Comment: what is your "data"?

Comment: you wrote [data objectForKey:@"username"]
For me, it is not clear what is data, how you initialise it and what is inside?

Comment: @user3233623 I've update my first suggestion in the answer, please, try it.

Comment: @Oleshko I just updated my original question with the proper data method.

Comment: @user3233623 please, post a body of that method and try my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

i think this will solve your problem

```
caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[params valueForKey:@"token"]];
```

Comment: Hey @Sachin Amrale , thanks for your reply. When I tried that line the compiler gives me the following warning `use of undeclared identifier params`. I like the idea of using the `params` dictionary to replace the `objectForKey` class instead. I will try multiple configurations. Update ahead